# Creating a separate text field effect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Honestly, I couldn't figure out how to best describe in the title what I would like to know how to achieve, so here is a gif which demonstrates that.

[image]

So, I came by this implementation and was wondering how this is implemented. I have an idea like there are tags for each text field and it is jumped to the next one if the current one's field is not empty. The problem is that I am not sure that it is the most "elegant" implementation.

So, I would be grateful if you have any general ideas how this could be achieved in a better way.